# What is the benefit of a sparse bindless texture array over just bindless textures?

Tags: opengl

I've seen the talks on AZDO, and they tend to suggest moving towards an architecture where you have one texture array per texture "shape". This is sparse, so you allocate loads of layers for potential future texture loads, and then commit each layer as you load a texture to it. You then make the whole thing bindless, and you can now pass a handle & layer to your shaders for texturing.

This is great, but what has it bought me above just using bindless textures? With bindless textures I seem to have to do exactly the same amount of work - in fact, a little less: I just pass in the texture handle (or sampler handle) to my shader.

So why the push for sparse bindless texture arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just pass in the texture handle (or sampler handle) to my shader.

OK, so you pass the handle to the shader. Well... how do you do that?

Different objects will have different texture handles. Therefore, you will have to pass different textures for rendering different objects. And that means you will either:

1. Change the value of a program's uniform.
2. Change the value of memory that will be used by that program.

Either one of these represents some form of state change. If you changed a buffer object's memory, then (to avoid synchronization) you need to now change what buffer that shader uses, so that it will see the value you just wrote. So that's a `glBindBufferRange` call.

The point of using an array texture (or a small set of them) is that *all of the textures* come from that array. So when you start rendering your scene, you pass the shader that texture (probably through a UBO). Then, every object will access that one texture through the one value that you set at the beginning of the frame. You never need to update any state, whether UBO or uniform state.

What array layer a particular model uses for that data would come from that model's per-object data. Just like any other per-object data.

Now, you could send a bunch of texture handles, and let the shader pick them out of an array. That is, rather than an array texture, you have an array **of** textures. But texture handles aren't free; they're 64-bit values. An array of upwards of 1000 of them is approximately 64KB. And the minimum that OpenGL 4.5 requires is only 16KB, so there's no guarantee that implementations will even allow a UBO that big.

You could use an SSBO for them, but that (often) represents slower access times: going out to global memory rather than reading a value from shader-local memory.

The purpose of it being sparse is just to avoid committing memory that you don't need. You'd allocate a large number of layers, but only commit memory for the layers that you upload actual textures to them.

Comment: Yes, an array of textures is exactly what I'm doing, backed behind a SSBO - hence wondering what a texture array was giving me (as I have no state changes with that approach). I should have clarified that. I didn't realise there was a cost of memory access though, I will do more research into that. Thank you!